# Javascript RegExp help

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace a certain text in Javascript.

newexp is a variable.
numexp is a variable

```
replacenamestring = new RegExp('Memberresumeexp\[1\]',"ig");
newexp = newexp.replace(replacenamestring,'Memberresumeexp[' + numexp + ']');
```

The above replace is not working.

How ever this works.

```
newexp = newexp.replace(/Memberresumeexp\[1\]/ig,'Memberresumeexp[' + numexp + ']');
```

Not able to figure out why?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Replace the part in between the `[]` with the value of `numexp`?

Comment: I am trying to replace Memberresumeexp[1] with Memberreusmeexp[newnumber which is a variable].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example for you with one BIG caveat -- I changed "[1]" to "[\d+]" just in case you needed this for more cases of `Memberresumeexp[<any number>]`.  Also, I hardcoded numexp, because I had not seen how it was initialized.

```
var replacenamestring = new RegExp('Memberresumeexp\\[\\d+\\]',"ig");

var newexp = "asdfasdflkj;lakwjef Memberresumeexp[1] asdfasdfasdf\nqwerqwerwer Memberresumeexp[2] qwerqwerwqerewr\n";

var numexp = 123;
if(replacenamestring.test(newexp))
{
    newexp = newexp.replace(replacenamestring,'Memberresumeexp[' + numexp + ']');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your first line creates a Javascript string, then parses the string as a regex.

Javascript string literals use `\` as an escape character, so the `\`s are not part of the string value. Therefore, the `[` and `]` in your regex aren't escaped, so it's creating a character class.
You need to escape the `\`s by writing `\\`.

Comment: replacenamestring = new RegExp('Memberresumeexp[1]',"ig"); Even this is not working. [] are part of the string.

Comment: Did you read my answer? You need to escape the `[` with escaped \ characters

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple lexical syntax issue. In the first case, you're creating the RegExp object with the constructor, which starts from a string constant.  Well, string constants have their own syntactic quirks, and in particular those backslashes in the **string** will be interpreted during its own parsing. By the time the RegExp constructor is called, those are **gone.**

The "native" RegExp syntax has its own quoting rules, which are such that the "[" and "]" portions of the pattern are correctly interpreted when you use that syntax.